# Simple normal baking - strange result

Tags: rendering, normals, texture-baking, baking, normal-map

I need to make a normal map (high poly to low poly).
But whatever I try I always get a really strange result.

Here is an example:
[image]
[image]
It is a shoe, the high and low poly models together. Low poly model have UV map, all the settings are on the screenshot. The normal map I'm getting is completely wrong.

I need to finish it until Monday, so I would be super grateful for your help! Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Maybe the same as this http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76416/how-to-bake-normal-map-if-the-models-intersect/76428#76428

Comment: @lemon  No, In this case I already increased the Ray Distance to maximum - the result is the same, so the problem remains.

Comment: When I look at the unusual high poly sculpting and the normal map it looks about right. Why do you feel it is wrong?

Comment: @photox I added a bigger screenshot of the UV map, compare to the model with sculpting it is wrong. The baked areas are square, they are smaller and less than should be.

Comment: Ok, that is odd.  I would need to see a blend, can you post one?

Comment: Maybe a scale problem (the highpoly, or both, is scaled): apply scales (ctrl+A in object mode). If not you should upload your file.